# Should I really get rep twice for two suggested edits on the same post?

Tags: support, edits, suggested-edits, reputation

I made an edit to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32573269/how-can-i-fold-blocks-of-comments-in-xcode-the-way-i-do-it-in-visual-studio) due to bad formatting (which I can't stand), and since I'm below 2k, I got the +2 rep for it.

Later on (maybe 30 minutes), after much banter in the comments and the data gleaned from them, I realized that there were also a few incorrect tags on that same question. So I did another "suggested" edit and removed those. That second edit was approved and I got *another* +2.

That seemed wrong to me. Is this correct behavior or something that was overlooked? It seems like I could just cheat my way to 2k by re-editing the same few posts in increments...

Here's the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32573269/revisions) for that question.

Comment: Don't worry, if you do that a couple of times (3+ edit suggestions on the same post), someone will notice and reign all the might of the community upon you (translation: get angry in chat and probably post a comment to one of your posts, maybe even flag for moderator attention). Nothing goes unnoticed here.

Comment: All this hullabaloo over imaginary unicorn points?

Comment: It's not just the *magical* imaginary unicorn points, @ShotgunNinja. It's the difference between catching the unicorn yourself, or buying it through some illegal exotic animal smuggler. It just didn't feel right...

Comment: Just keep providing good content and the site will keep giving you lots of points that don't cost them anything. They call that win/win, except you can't really redeem your points for anything other than what other people will give you for them (as bounties, maybe their knowledge and research time?)

Comment: @AaronHall - Privileges. That's what you get for points. I'm looking forward to seeing deleted content (10K), protecting questions (15K), and seeing the site analytics (25K). Being a Trusted User doesn't really interest me (20K).

Comment: Related: [Extra conditions for gaining reputation from editing the tag wiki once created](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142706/extra-conditions-for-gaining-reputation-from-editing-the-tag-wiki-once-created).

Comment: I brought this question up some years ago on [meta prime](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79588).

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Ideally you should have made all the edits on one go, but both your edits were deemed to be useful so you got the +2 for each. There's nothing wrong with this and to change the system so you only could get one +2 per post would probably be far too complicated for the actual benefit (if indeed there was a benefit) that it would bring.

The only thing I can suggest is that you take a little longer over the edits and review them yourself before hitting "Done".

Comment: I agree on making all the edits in one go, but I didn't feel it justifiable to remove those tags at first. Once I read some more from the comments, I felt that removing them was the correct way to go. I see I lost one of the +2 , thanks(?).

Comment: @CaptJak you still have both +2's. And unless the post is deleted you'll always have both. If your rep just went down by 2 then you must have either unaccepted an answer on one of your questions or been on the receiving end of a down-vote.

Comment: Strange, it showed 1971 on meta when I wrote the question, now it says 1969, but on SO it shows 1971...

Comment: @CaptJak. caching. You must have lost 2 points, then your score was copied to meta, then you regained those points. Give it a bit longer and your meta rep will catch up.

Comment: OK... I'll shut up.