# I appear to have gotten rep twice for one edit

Tags: support, bug, specific-edit

I made an edit to the [tag wiki for AspectJ](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6746984/revisions).

If you look at the history, someone corrected an error I made (I accidentally had "of" in there twice in a row) right after I made my edit. Since this was someone with +2K rep, I suspect they did an "Approve & Edit" on my edit, which would explain why the edit summary is also the same.

However, I got a notification a few minutes ago that I earned another +2 rep for the same edit:

[image: Image showing the rep notification on the top bar displaying "+2 Tag wiki suggested edit was approved" at the top and the user activity page showing "+2 1 hour ago edit tag wiki" and "+2 15 minutes ago edit tag wiki"]

I've only made one tag wiki edit today (this is only the 2nd or 3rd I've ever done) and both tag wiki links on my Reputation tab go to the same wiki.

This seems like a bug. I shouldn't get +2 more rep just because someone had to fix a mistake I made, right?

NOTE: This is not a duplicate of, [Should I really get rep twice for two suggested edits on the same post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306062/should-i-really-get-rep-twice-for-two-suggested-edits-on-the-same-question), which is about editing the same post twice. This is about editing a post once but getting rep twice.

Comment: One was for the excerpt, the other was for the wiki, two edits, two times two is four. It is kind of confusing that it doesn't differentiate between tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt in the dropdown. It shows the difference on the [activity page](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4076315/bsmp?tab=topactivity)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You edited *both* the wiki and the excerpt, and both were approved. For this, you got +2 for *each* edit.

The wiki history:

[image]

The excerpt history:

[image]

If I remember correctly, you can edit both from the same page. This is likely why you thought you only made one edit. (Along with the achievement dropdown and rep pages being less explicit than desired.)

Comment: You do remember correctly and that's exactly why I thought they counted as one edit.